# An interesting identity involving triangle numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $T^{(2)}_i$ be 1 for $i = 1,2,\dots$ and  $T^{(3)}_i$ be the natural numbers $T^{(4)}_i$  be the triangular numbers $T^{(5)}_i$ be the tetrahedral numbers and so on for $i = 1,2,\dots$

For $m = 2,3,\dots, n-1$, show that 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-m} i \sum_{j=1}^{n-i-m+1}T^{(m)}_j=  \frac{(n)!}{(m+1)!(n-(m+1))!}
\end{equation}

This works for the case $m = 2$ and I have tried to construct an inductive argument to prove this result.  On the other hand $\frac{(n)!}{(m+1)!(n-(m+1))!}$ is $n$ choose $m+1$ and I thought there might be a slick way to answer this question.

Comment: Where are the $i$ and $j$ over which the summation goes used? Should it be $T^{(m)}_i$ or $T^{(m)}_j$ perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Ragnar.  I've edited the question now :)

Comment: Do you mean $T^{(j)}_i$?   $T^{(j)}$ is a set.

Comment: Mathematica tells me this is not always true, for example, take $(n,m)=(7,4)$. Then the LHS gives $20$ but $\binom 75=21$.